# Precision paper cutter

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

I have carefully positioned some words on the cutting edge of a paper cutter:

```
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓     
        ┃B A R S T O O L┃     
        ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓   
          ┃P I N T A I L S┃   
          ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛   
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
      ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓       
      ┃H E A D S H O T┃       
      ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓     
          ┃E Y E W A L L┃     
          ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓       
        ┃K I N G P I N┃       
        ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓     
          ┃I N G R A I N┃     
          ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓       
          ┃S E L V E S┃       
          ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓       
          ┃G E R M A N┃       
          ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓     
            ┃E R R I N G┃     
            ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓     
            ┃A L T A R S┃     
            ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓     
            ┃A L P I N E┃     
            ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓         
        ┃R I P E S T┃         
        ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓     
            ┃E N L I S T┃     
            ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━━━┓         
          ┃B O W E L┃         
          ┗━━━━━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━┓       
            ┃A S I D E┃       
            ┗━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━┓       
            ┃A R S O N┃       
            ┗━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━┓       
            ┃A R C E D┃       
            ┗━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━┓       
            ┃A N G L E┃       
            ┗━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━┓       
            ┃A L L O Y┃       
            ┗━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━┓       
            ┃S E V E R┃       
            ┗━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━━━┓         
          ┃P A S T A┃         
          ┗━━━━━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━━━┓       
            ┃P E T R I┃       
            ┗━━━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━┓         
            ┃W I K I┃         
            ┗━━━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━┓         
            ┃I S L E┃         
            ┗━━━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━┓         
            ┃L Y R E┃         
            ┗━━━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━┓         
            ┃M E S A┃         
            ┗━━━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━┓         
            ┃C H I N┃         
            ┗━━━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━┓         
            ┃D E M O┃         
            ┗━━━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━━━┓         
            ┃O N T O┃         
            ┗━━━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓ 
              ┃E M A N A T E┃ 
              ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛ 
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
      ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓           
      ┃E I G H T H┃           
      ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━━━┓     
              ┃E T H O S┃     
              ┗━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━━━┓     
              ┃E T H E R┃     
              ┗━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃A N G E R┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃O U G H T┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃O U T E R┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃E A S E L┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃E A R T H┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━━━┓     
              ┃C I L I A┃     
              ┗━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━┓       
              ┃P R O M┃       
              ┗━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃R I O T┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃R A P T┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━┓       
              ┃R U S E┃       
              ┗━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━┓       
              ┃N O P E┃       
              ┗━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃E A R N┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃E A S T┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃A C H E┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━┓       
              ┃A I D E┃       
              ┗━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃A M E N┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃A N E W┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━┓       
              ┃F L E A┃       
              ┗━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━┓       
              ┃E M U S┃       
              ┗━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━┓       
              ┃E E L S┃       
              ┗━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━┓       
              ┃F R E E┃       
              ┗━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━┓       
              ┃G R I N┃       
              ┗━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃H I N T┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃L U M P┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃L E A P┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃I T E M┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━┓           
            ┃P E A┃           
            ┗━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━┓         
              ┃N O W┃         
              ┗━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━┓         
              ┃L O W┃         
              ┗━━━━━┛         
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━┓           
            ┃I N K┃           
            ┗━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━┓           
            ┃H O W┃           
            ┗━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓   
              ┃D E L U D E┃   
              ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛   
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━┓       
              ┃D I C E┃       
              ┗━━━━━━━┛       
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
  ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓           
  ┃E D I T I O N S┃           
  ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
  ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓           
  ┃W I N D L E S S┃           
  ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓   
              ┃S T R U C K┃   
              ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛   
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
      ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓           
      ┃C A R E S S┃           
      ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
      ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓           
      ┃E X I S T S┃           
      ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
      ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓           
      ┃H A V E N S┃           
      ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
      ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓           
      ┃E L E C T S┃           
      ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
      ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓           
      ┃H O V E L S┃           
      ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
      ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓           
      ┃L A Y E R S┃           
      ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃L I M E S┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃H U N T S┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃I D L E S┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃H I R E S┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃H A R P S┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
        ┏━━━━━━━━━┓           
        ┃H A R K S┃           
        ┗━━━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━━━┓     
              ┃S W A R M┃     
              ┗━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━━━┓     
              ┃S U R G E┃     
              ┗━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━━━┓     
              ┃S W O R D┃     
              ┗━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
              ┏━━━━━━━━━┓     
              ┃S W I N E┃     
              ┗━━━━━━━━━┛     
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃P A S S┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃K I S S┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃O A K S┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃O A R S┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃O I L S┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃O R E S┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃O U R S┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
          ┏━━━━━━━┓           
          ┃H O E S┃           
          ┗━━━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃                                  
            ┏━━━━━┓           
            ┃I T S┃           
            ┗━━━━━┛           
                ┃                                                           
                ┃
```

*SHHHWACK!!*

What am I planning to do with the pieces?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that you're

> planning to switch both sides of them. Each of these words forms a new word when you take the two pieces and swap them; for example, BARS✂️TOOL and PIN✂️TAILS become TOOLBARS and TAILSPIN.

A full list of the results:

> `BARS✂TOOL     → TOOL|BARS
>      PIN✂TAILS    → TAILS|PIN
>    HEADS✂HOT      → HOT|HEADS
>      EYE✂WALL     → WALL|EYE
>     KING✂PIN      → PIN|KING
>      ING✂RAIN     → RAIN|ING
>      SEL✂VES      → VES|SEL
>      GER✂MAN      → MAN|GER
>       ER✂RING     → RING|ER
>       AL✂TARS     → TARS|AL
>       AL✂PINE     → PINE|AL
>     RIPE✂ST       → ST|RIPE
>       EN✂LIST     → LIST|EN
>      BOW✂EL       → EL|BOW
>       AS✂IDE      → IDE|AS
>       AR✂SON      → SON|AR
>       AR✂CED      → CED|AR
>       AN✂GLE      → GLE|AN
>       AL✂LOY      → LOY|AL
>       SE✂VER      → VER|SE
>      PAS✂TA       → TA|PAS
>       PE✂TRI      → TRI|PE
>       WI✂KI       → KI|WI
>       IS✂LE       → LE|IS
>       LY✂RE       → RE|LY
>       ME✂SA       → SA|ME
>       CH✂IN       → IN|CH
>       DE✂MO       → MO|DE
>       ON✂TO       → TO|ON
>        E✂MANATE   → MANATE|E
>    EIGHT✂H        → H|EIGHT
>        E✂THOS     → THOS|E
>        E✂THER     → THER|E
>     ANGE✂R        → R|ANGE
>     OUGH✂T        → T|OUGH
>     OUTE✂R        → R|OUTE
>     EASE✂L        → L|EASE
>     EART✂H        → H|EART
>        C✂ILIA     → ILIA|C
>        P✂ROM      → ROM|P
>      RIO✂T        → T|RIO
>      RAP✂T        → T|RAP
>        R✂USE      → USE|R
>        N✂OPE      → OPE|N
>      EAR✂N        → N|EAR
>      EAS✂T        → T|EAS
>      ACH✂E        → E|ACH
>        A✂IDE      → IDE|A
>      AME✂N        → N|AME
>      ANE✂W        → W|ANE
>        F✂LEA      → LEA|F
>        E✂MUS      → MUS|E
>        E✂ELS      → ELS|E
>        F✂REE      → REE|F
>        G✂RIN      → RIN|G
>      HIN✂T        → T|HIN
>      LUM✂P        → P|LUM
>      LEA✂P        → P|LEA
>      ITE✂M        → M|ITE
>       PE✂A        → A|PE
>        N✂OW       → OW|N
>        L✂OW       → OW|L
>       IN✂K        → K|IN
>       HO✂W        → W|HO
>        D✂ELUDE    → ELUDE|D
>        D✂ICE      → ICE|D
>  EDITION✂S        → S|EDITION
>  WINDLES✂S        → S|WINDLES
>        S✂TRUCK    → TRUCK|S
>    CARES✂S        → S|CARES
>    EXIST✂S        → S|EXIST
>    HAVEN✂S        → S|HAVEN
>    ELECT✂S        → S|ELECT
>    HOVEL✂S        → S|HOVEL
>    LAYER✂S        → S|LAYER
>     LIME✂S        → S|LIME
>     HUNT✂S        → S|HUNT
>     IDLE✂S        → S|IDLE
>     HIRE✂S        → S|HIRE
>     HARP✂S        → S|HARP
>     HARK✂S        → S|HARK
>        S✂WARM     → WARM|S
>        S✂URGE     → URGE|S
>        S✂WORD     → WORD|S
>        S✂WINE     → WINE|S
>      PAS✂S        → S|PAS
>      KIS✂S        → S|KIS
>      OAK✂S        → S|OAK
>      OAR✂S        → S|OAR
>      OIL✂S        → S|OIL
>      ORE✂S        → S|ORE
>      OUR✂S        → S|OUR
>      HOE✂S        → S|HOE
>       IT✂S        → S|IT`